# Update the expression of a image field in SSRS from report server

Tags: reporting-services

Recently we moved from SSRS 2014  SharePoint mode to native mode. We were able to migrate all the reports but the logos for the reports are defined as expression below, these are external images.
"
Iif(len(Globals!ReportFolder)>0,
Mid(Globals!ReportFolder,1, Iif(InStr(Globals!ReportFolder,"Report Center")>0,InStr(Globals!ReportFolder,"Report Center")-1,0)) & "SiteAssets/ReportImage.PNG",
Globals!ReportServerUrl & "SiteAssets/ReportImage.PNG"):

since the 2019 SSRS reports  url is different than the old one( 2014 sharepoint) we have to update 1000+ report's logos. I tried to update the content column in the catalog table with the new url. though it says rows updated, when I view in the XML format, it shows the old one.

Below is what I am doing:

SELECT
ItemID,
[Path]
, CASE [Type]
WHEN 2 THEN 'Report'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source'
END AS TypeName
,Content
, CAST(CAST(content AS varbinary(max)) AS xml) contentxml
, [Description]
into ##rep
FROM ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] CTG
WHERE
[Type] IN (2, 5) and ItemID='6A4A5246-94FC-4BEF-87F2-716067839E44'

UPDATE ##rep
SET contentxml = REPLACE(CAST(contentxml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '=Iif(len(Globals!ReportFolder)>0,
Mid(Globals!ReportFolder,1, Iif(InStr(Globals!ReportFolder,"Report Center")>0,InStr(Globals!ReportFolder,"Report Center")-1,0)) & "SiteAssets/ReportImage.PNG",
Globals!ReportServerUrl & "SiteAssets/ReportImage.PNG")', '=/SiteAssets/ReportImage.png')
WHERE ItemID = '6A4A5246-94FC-4BEF-87F2-716067839E44'

Is there any other way we can update the catalog table so that it updates all the reports logo's URL at once instead of opening each report and update manually.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you not have the RDL's in a Visual Studio solution(s)? If you do , just open the parent folder in VS (or VS Code), hit Shift+Ctrl+H and do a search replace on all the source files. Then just deploy.

Comment: There are about 1000 reports which we need to do this. Its very tedious to open and update for 1000 reports the same

Comment: If you open the folder the RDL's are contained in and do Shift+Ctrl+H you can do a single search replace on all files in a single step, it's a 5 minute job. From VS Code for example, do "File" then "Open Folder", no need to open each file.

Comment: how could you open reports on a report server in visual studio.  I believe we have to download to local and do it Pretending this is the URL -"http://xxxx/reports/browse/xxxx"

Comment: That's why I asked "Do you not have the RDL's in a Visual Studio solution(s)? ". If you don't, you probably should, or you have no version control, backups etc.. You can download them all via PowerShell, lots of sample code out there to do it, like this https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/09/ssrs-snack-download-all-ssrs-reports.html